# how to properly overload kotlin data class with constructors

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create a nested data class in kotlin which contain several other data classes. Then access the main data class to get the objects of the nested data class.

`Person` data class is going to be the standard, but the other 3 data classes are the overloaded ones (not sure if i'm using the term overload correctly here?).

Note: the ide i'm using is intellij

What I mean:

```
data class User(val person: Person, val transport: Transport)
{
    constructor(person: Person, activity: Activity): this(person, activity)  //ERROR: There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain
    constructor(person: Person, absent: Absent): this(person, absent)  //ERROR: There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain
}

data class Activity(val game: String, val funLevel: Int)
data class Absent(val isSick: Boolean, val funLevel: Int)
data class Transport(val typeOfTransport: String)
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun main(){
    val x = User(Person("foo", 5), Activity("basketball", 10))
    val y = User(Person("bar", 6), Absent(true, 0))
    val z = User(Person("loo", 6), Transport("Bus"))
    
    // Ultimately want to access the data objects like this
    println(x.person.name)
    println(x.activity.game)  // not working
    
}
```

Ultimately, I am trying to be able to call the function easily based like this:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: So a user has an activity, a transport, xor an absent? Is that what you're proposing? What you're describing is *not* a dataclass. A dataclass is a simple product of types wrapped in a class. Remember that Kotlin is a statically-typed language, so what happens if I have a `User` initialized with a `Transport` and then I do `x.activity`? Is it `null`? An exception? You need to write a class (not a data class) that encapsulates whichever behavior you want.

Comment: Try to use [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html) for second parameter in `User` class

Comment: I see. OK so it might make sense to have it as a class instead of data class? Sorry I'm still learning kotlin, so this really helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data class User(val person: Person, val transport: Transport)
```

That bit in the parentheses there is the *primary constructor* - in fact that's shorthand, you can also write the class declaration like this:

```
data class User constructor(val person: Person, val transport: Transport)
```

When you have a primary constructor, [any secondary constructors have to call through to the primary one](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#secondary-constructors).

```
// need to somehow create a Transport to call the primary with
constructor(person: Person, activity: Activity): this(person, someTransport)

// can't do this - the primary constructor doesn't take (Person, Activity)
constructor(person: Person, activity: Activity): this(person, activity)
```

That's because to actually *create an instance of a class*, you need to call its main constructor at some point - the secondaries can just do *other stuff* as well, but they need to actually instantiate the object.

---

You can omit the primary constructor (so the class can be instantiated with no arguments) and then your secondary constructors can do whatever they want:

```
class User {
    constructor(person: Person, activity: Activity) {
        // initialisation stuff
    }
    constructor(person: Person, absent: Absent) {
        // other initialisation stuff
    }
}
```

but at the end of the day it's still calling that no-args constructor to actually create the `User` - it's up to you to *do something* with those different arguments passed into the different constructors, and create *the same type of object* no matter which is called.

Do you have all the possible properties, and just leave them null if no value was provided? Do you have a special set of classes representing the different combos of data for each constructor, and assign an instance of one of those to a `userData` property? You need to work out how to have a single class that can be instantiated with different combinations of data.

---

[Data classes are special](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html), and **require** a primary constructor. That's actually what defines the *data* in the class, and all its handy overridden and generated methods (like `equals`, `hashCode`, `copy`) all work with those properties defined in the primary constructor.

The flipside of that is **any property not defined in or derived from the primary constructor's parameters is not part of its "data"**. If you `copy` a data class, only the properties in the primary constructor are copied. It doesn't know anything about the rest of the class - so if you're relying on any of the data class features, be aware that other properties are not included by default.

So with that in mind, a typical data class approach would be to have *all* your data in the primary constructor:

```
data class User(
    val person: Person,
    val transport: Transport? = null,
    val activity: Activity? = null,
    val absent: Absent? = null
) {
    constructor(person: Person, activity: Activity): this(person, null, activity, null)
    constructor(person: Person, absent: Absent): this(person, null, null, absent)
}
```

That way every secondary constructor calls the main one, and all your data is defined and contained in the primary constructor. Some things just might be missing!

---

This is a bit awkward though:

```
this(person, null, activity, null)
```

We have named arguments, so you could try this:

```
constructor(person: Person, activity: Activity): this(person, activity = activity)
```

But that will actually call the same secondary constructor again, because its signature (takes a `Person` and an `Activity`) matches the call you're making. (That's why you're getting the cyclic error.) But if we're doing things this way, with default arguments, you can avoid the secondary constructors completely:

```
data class User(
    val person: Person,
    val transport: Transport? = null,
    val activity: Activity? = null,
    val absent: Absent? = null
)

// create an instance
User(somePerson, absent = someAbsent)
```

But this way limits your ability to restrict it to certain combinations, like a `Person` and *one of* `Transport`/`Activity`/`Absent`. That's a problem with data classes in general - you can make the primary constructor `private` and force users to go through secondary constructors or other functions that generate an instance, but the `copy` function allows people to mess with that data however they like.

In this case, you probably want [a sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html) like *IR42* mentions in the comments - a type which allows for a defined set of completely different subclasses. I just wanted to give an overview of how this all works and why maybe you'd want to try a different approach